# Is there a substitute that can be used instead of the included STL on the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, visual-studio, xcode, stl

I am currently using the STL included with the iPhone SDK.  I haven't been able to find a way in the Xcode debugger to look at data that is in a list, map, etc. like I can within Visual Studio.  Within Visual Studio, I can walk through the data structure and look at the data within the list, map, etc.  Within Xcode, this doesn't seem to work the same way.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Boost isn't a substitute for the STL, it complements the STL (and more).

Answer (score 1):

In my version of xcode there seems to be some support for containers in the debugger - I'm running 3.2 installed off my OS Disk and when I make vector classes I can browse through their elements - they appear just as arrays do, although it can't always handle a vector within a vector, and other more complex scenarios.

I'm not really to sure why its not working for you, but I would recommend the following:

a) Make sure you have the latest version of xcode available.

b) Try the vector class specifically, I can vouch for it working in my version - whether or not you want to use this class that'll help the troubleshooting process.

c) Try using the vector at global level rather then indented within loads of structures.

d) If its really irritating you then its possible installing xcode off your install disk would help (unless already had it previous to downloading the iPhone SDK). I'm not to sure if there is a difference, and I don't see the sense in there being any though (probably wise to ask the community in another question).